# error CS1647: An expression is too long or complex to compile

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio, compiler-construction, compiler-errors

I cant find a clear cut solution to this error that happens for a new project in Visual Studio 2010.  It doesnt tell me where it's happening at all, just inside the website.  Any clue on where I should look to fix this issue?

```
(0,0): error CS1647: An expression is too long or complex to compile
Validation Complete
========== Build: 2 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is a compiler bug.  From [Connect](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/785173/got-error-cs1647-an-expression-is-too-long-or-complex-to-compile-in-vs2012):

> Unfortunately, there's not much we can do here without isolating the
>   issue further. Usually, this error results from a deeply chained
>   expression in your source, such as a long chain of string
>   concatenations ("aaaa" + "bbbb" + ...). Such expressions are parsed
>   and bound recursively in the compiler, and there is a depth at which
>   the compiler will run out of stack space to continue parsing. The
>   exact expression complexity supported depends on the data stashed in
>   the compiler's stack frames, which can vary subtly between updates -
>   if an expression in your solution was right at the boundary before, it
>   may have tipped over.

I recommend looking for long string concatenations, multi-line math formulas, etc.

Comment: Yea hard to do with hundreds of files.

Comment: You could open a support ticket with Microsoft.